# How to query the available data size in Linux DVB kernel demux buffers?

Tags: linux, buffer, polling, dvb, v4l

I am using a Linux-DVB frontend/demux driver pair to get a program stream remuxed from live broadcast TS into user land. I am using the poll/read combination, however, to keep the context switching and kernel to user space copying penalties at minimum, I only want to read data if it is bigger than a certain size.

I couldn't find any way to query the available data size in the demux buffers nor any option to specify the poll notify size.

Is anybody aware of any such functionality? If not, is it unreasonable to have such a feature request on the DVB api?

Regards,

Comment: It really sounds like you're asking about the Linux kernel's `DVB` subsystem, which is located and maintained in the media tree *with* `V4L`, but not actually `video4linux` itself.  By 'live ts' do you mean a DVB-T broadcast?

Comment: Yes, your deductions are correct and sorry for the misused terminology. My code is interfaced with the kernel's dvb subsystem and it's a dvb-t/t2 frontend. The proprietary drivers for the embedded platform I'm using only have the frontend and demux device nodes but no dvr